# How to stop the execution of a method after a specific time in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

How can I implement this logic under iOS (Objective-C)?

```
  [obj method1]

  [OCRlib imageScan] // run <10 sec. or should be stopped.
                     // Display progress bar during execution.
                     // If does not finish in 10 seconds - stop it.
                     // OCRlib - third-party code I can't change

  [obj method2]      // wait imageScan results here
```

I saw answers for Java/C# here but not for Objective-C..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to stop the `imageScan` method, does `OCRlib` provide a method to that effect?

To acheive the timeout you can use dispatch groups

```
[obj method1]

dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    [OCRlib imageScan]
});

dispatch_time_t when = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,NSEC_PER_SEC * timeout);
long status = dispatch_group_wait(group, when );

if (status != 0) {
    // block completed
    [obj method2]
}
else {
    // block failed to complete in timeout
}
```

Comment: No, OCRlib in my case does not provide a method for timeout. Thanks, I will try.

Comment: Is it possible in Objective-C to run imageScan method in separate thread and kill this thread after 10 seconds?

Comment: `NSThread` has an `+exit` function which kills the current thread, but gives the api recommends avoiding this facility. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/exit).

Comment: status == 0 should be // block completed